# Mysqli update won't work

Tags: php, cookies, mysqli, authentication, insert

Being specific - I'd like to operate on cookies when it comes to login handling, therefore I set cookie "session_token" to be openssl_random_pseudo_bytes.

```
setcookie( "session_token", bin2hex( openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( 32 ) ), time() + 600 );
```

But then, I'd like it to be the value which "token" in a database is updated with.
However, what I get, is empty database field, where generated token should be.

Code:

$flogin is the post data passed to login function.

```
$conn->query( "UPDATE Client SET token='" .$_COOKIE['session_token']. "' WHERE login='" .$flogin. "'" );
```

Cookie is 64-characters long, so is the "token" field in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use parameterized queries. Do you get any errors currently?

Comment: Do you set the cookie and update the table on the same script/request ?

Comment: all I've to say is "check for errors" and make sure the column's length is long enough.

Comment: @chris85
Thank you for the advice on parameterized queries. I do not get any errors with query, neither when establishing database connection.

Comment: If you echo the query and execute it on your database does it work as expected?

Comment: `setcookie` will tell the browser to create a cookie so `$_COOKIE['session_token']` will not be populated during this time. Only when the browser send the created cookie will the `$_COOKIE` be populated. So the `$_COOKIE` should be available on the next request after the `setcookie`

Comment: @chris85 Surprisingly, it does.

Comment: @frz3993 It is available on each next request, what explains the "outdated" cookie value. But even on attempted second request it won't update the column. I'll experiment with the code to find out whether execution in singular script is the issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

LifeParser wrote:

`INSERT` statement works like a charm.

I like self answers. Unfortunately he wrote it in the question so I moved it here.